# Enable mouseup / mousedown but prevent click behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, events, dom-events

I have a data visualization here (the second one):

http://mikeheavers.com/main/work

If you click on the circles representing skill fields, it reveals inner green circles with the particular skills. If you hold down on the green circles representing the skills, they animate, grow, and then shrink back on mouse release. However, if you simply click on the circles, they grow, but do not return to their previous size (the `mousedown` is not registered I guess) - which results in a circle that will constantly get bigger each time it is clicked.

Is there a way to prevent click behaviour, either through d3 or through Javascript / jQuery? I only want `mouseup` and `mousedown`.

Comment: It looks like you're just reapplying d3 examples I've seen.  Where's the original example upon which you're basing this one?

Comment: Well, there's no example that utilizes circle packing with click / mouse down behaviors - I added all that myself, but the original, non-interactive circle packing example is here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530

Comment: Got it.  I was thinking of this one, which I thought did something similar to what you're seeking: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/09/04/us/politics/democratic-convention-words.html.  I probably won't be useful to solving this one, but good luck.

Comment: Poking at that example I sent, it looks like they disable drag like so: `p.on("click.drag",null)`.  There might be an equivalent `p.on("click",null)`.

Comment: `click.drag` is just a `click` action that is additionally labeled with `drag`. This allows multiple "click" actions to be attached to a particular element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm observing different behavior than what you described.

- If you single click a circle, it doesn't matter how long the click is (whether it's held or not), it returns back to its original size.
- If you click a circle repeatedly and quickly, this is when it starts to grow and does not return to its original size.
- If you hold down a circle and then move your mouse outside of it, it both stays pink and doesn't return to its original size.

I think attaching a simple `.on('mouseout', handler)` to return spheres to their original size will solve the last issue, which is pretty glaring, and any missed `mouseup` events due to moving outside. You can also attach a `mouseup` to the whole document (`d3.select('body').on('mouseup', handler)`), which will catch any such event; then you would just need to record the last sphere that was clicked.

Additionally, to fix your original problem, you can make sure that `mouseup` events are triggered by adding `e.preventDefault()` in the `mousedown` events. This will prevent fast clicks from turning into double-clicks or other events by the browser.

Other posts that discuss these issues:

- [mouseup event isn't always triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410112/mouseup-event-isnt-always-triggered)
- [mouseUp event on drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019190/mouseup-event-on-drag)